How can I create a custom case when expression for a property for EF Core?
I'd like to create a custom expression for ef core that will get translated to a case when sql query
Let's say that I have a TestModel that looks like this
public class TestModel 
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

When querying for it, I would like to produce the following sql statement
SELECT 
    Key,
    CASE 
         WHEN Value = 'Foo' THEN 'Bar'
         WHEN Value = 'Bar' THEN 'Baz'
    ELSE Value
    END as Value
FROM TestTable

However, I would like to do this in a generic manner, based on a custom lookup that I can provide to the method call. So, assuming that I have a DbSet, I would like to have the following generic api available when querying
Dictionary<string, string> valueLookup;

models
    .CaseWhen(
      propertySelector: model => model.Value,
      valueLookup: valueLookup)
     .{WhateverOtherMethod}

For this, I'd need to have something like this implemented as an extension method. For the sake of the example, you can ignore the generic dictionary constraint, it's not as important
    public static IQueryable<TEntity> CaseWhen<TEntity, TProperty, TLookup>(
        this IQueryable<TEntity> query,
        Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>> propertySelector,
        TLookup lookup)
            where TLookup : IDictionary<TProperty, TProperty>

I've implemented the conditional, which can actually translate to roughly what I want
        var entity = propertySelector.Parameters.First();
        var propertyMember = (MemberExpression)propertySelector.Body;

        var cases = lookup
            .Select(kvp =>
                Expression.Condition(
                    Expression.Equal(propertyMember, Expression.Constant(kvp.Key)),
                    Expression.Constant(kvp.Value),
                    propertyMember))
            .ToArray();

        var condition = cases
            .Aggregate((cond, next) =>
                Expression.Condition(
                    cond.Test,
                    cond,
                    next));

        var conditionExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, TProperty>>(condition, entity);

However, this is a conditional expression for this one property, which will translate to just returning one column. And so far I've been struggling to produce the next expression set to return the actual entity, so I can return this:
Expression<Func<TEntity, TEntity>> finalExpression = {Final Code}

return query.Select(finalExpression)

How do I produce the expression to still use my conditional expression and select the provided entity as the output?
I also want to be able to chain this method for multiple properties, so I don't want to just hardcode any other properties being queried for it.
I know that ef core can already translate ternary operators into case when statements, but I've struggled to find the code that actually does it, so if you can link me to how a provider implements this, and I could replicate it, I would still consider it as a superb answer.
Thanks!

I do not understand why function CaseWhen returns the same entity. Do you plan to assign to some property this generated expression?

Yes, the idea is that a single property will have a case/when applied to it. You can check out the query I want to produce to see the exact result I was trying to achieve

I've messed around with it some more and figured out how to achieve what I wanted. Posting the code in case someone wants to have the same
public static IQueryable<TEntity> CaseWhen<TEntity, TProperty, TLookup>(
    this IQueryable<TEntity> query,
    Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>> propertySelector,
    TLookup lookup)
        where TLookup : IDictionary<TProperty, TProperty>
{
    // Get entity info
    ParameterExpression entity = propertySelector.Parameters.First();
    MemberExpression propertyMember = (MemberExpression)propertySelector.Body;

    // Default case is just our property
    Expression condition = propertyMember;

    // Aggregate other cases into a nested condition
    condition = lookup
        .Aggregate(
            seed: condition,
            func: (cond, next) =>
                Expression.Condition(
                    Expression.Equal(propertyMember, Expression.Constant(next.Key)),
                    Expression.Constant(next.Value),
                    cond)
        );

    // Create new entity instance
    NewExpression newExpression = Expression.New(typeof(TEntity));

    // Create member binding for the case/when property
    MemberAssignment propertyAssign = Expression.Bind(propertyMember.Member, condition);

    // Find other properties of the entity
    IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> otherProperties = typeof(TEntity)
        .GetProperties()
        .Where(pi => pi != propertyMember.Member
            && pi.GetCustomAttribute<NotMappedAttribute>() is null);

    // Translate other properties to member expressions
    IEnumerable<MemberExpression> otherMembers = otherProperties
        .Select(pi =>
            Expression.MakeMemberAccess(entity, pi));

    // Assign the values to other members
    IEnumerable<MemberAssignment> otherAssignments = otherMembers
        .Select(prop =>
            Expression.Bind(
                prop.Member,
                prop));

    // Concat the case/when assignment with other property assignments
    IEnumerable<MemberAssignment> allAssignments = Enumerable
        .Repeat(propertyAssign, 1)
        .Concat(otherAssignments);

    // Create a new entity from what we have
    MemberInitExpression initExpression = Expression.MemberInit(
        newExpression, 
        allAssignments);

    // ???
    Expression<Func<TEntity, TEntity>> finalExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, TEntity>>(
        initExpression,
        entity);

    // Profit!
    return query.Select(finalExpression);
}

Here's an example usage
public class TestModel
{
    [Key]
    public required string Key { get; set; }

    public required string Value { get; set; }

    public required int Something { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string? Heya { get; set; }
}

public class TestDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<TestModel> Models { get; set; }

    public TestDbContext(
        DbContextOptions<TestDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
}


DbContextOptions<TestDbContext> options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<TestDbContext>()
    .UseSqlServer("")
    .Options;

TestDbContext context = new(options);
DbSet<TestModel> models = context.Models;

Dictionary<string, string> lookup = new()
{
    { "Foo", "Bar" },
    { "Bar", "Baz" },
};

Dictionary<int, int> lookup2 = new()
{
    { 1, 2 },
    { 2, 3 },
};


string query = models
    .CaseWhen(
        propertySelector: model => model.Key,
        lookup: lookup)
    .CaseWhen(
        propertySelector: model => model.Something,
        lookup: lookup2)
    .ToQueryString();

This will produce the following query
SELECT CASE
    WHEN [m].[Something] = 2 THEN 3
    WHEN [m].[Something] = 1 THEN 2
    ELSE [m].[Something]
END AS [Something], CASE
    WHEN [m].[Key] = N'Bar' THEN N'Baz'
    WHEN [m].[Key] = N'Foo' THEN N'Bar'
    ELSE [m].[Key]
END AS [Key], [m].[Value]
FROM [Models] AS [m]

Which is what I was looking for exactly
